# server timeout when install xtream ui

Tags: server, 18.04, ssh, mysql

when i try to install xtream on my ubuntu server 18.04.6 with this lines

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get install mysql-server && sudo apt-get install python && sudo apt install apache2 && sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev && sudo apt-get install libgeoip-dev && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
wget https://lofertech.com/xui/install.py
sudo python install.py
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqRHK.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvlUj.png
and go to admin panel i see this error (time out)

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

ps: Admin UI: http://10.0.0.4:25500 this not my server ip i don't know why give me this adress
my server ip start with 4.**.***.11

```
 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │                                          │
 │                                          │
 │       Xtream UI - Installer Mirror       │
 │                                          │
 │                                          │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 │ NOTE: this is a forked mirror of original installer from emre1393/xtream-ui.c                                                                                                             om
 │ Paid Service On Telegram @lofertech & Youtube = LoferTech Official.
 │ For more information visit lofertech.com

  Installation Type [MAIN, LB, UPDATE]: Main

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │          Start installation? Y/N         │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

  Y

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │          Preparing Installation          │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │      Removing libcurl4 if installed      │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │            Installing libcurl3           │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │          Installing libxslt1-dev         │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │          Installing libgeoip-dev         │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │           Installing e2fsprogs           │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │              Installing wget             │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │             Installing mcrypt            │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │              Installing nscd             │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │              Installing htop             │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │              Installing zip              │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │             Installing unzip             │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │               Installing mc              │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │          Installing libjemalloc1         │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │        Installing python-paramiko        │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │          Installing mysql-server         │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │             Installing libpng            │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │         Creating user xtreamcodes        │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │           Downloading Software           │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │            Installing Software           │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │             Configuring MySQL            │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │        Enter MySQL Root Password:        │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

  DviL2MghIe37W4r5ocq

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │   Drop existing & create database? Y/N   │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

  Y
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │               Encrypting...              │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │            Configuring System            │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │              Modifying Nginx             │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │          Installing Admin Panel          │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │        Downloading Software Update       │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │             Updating Software            │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │           Starting Xtream Codes          │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

no crontab for xtreamcodes
no crontab for xtreamcodes
 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │                                          │
 │                                          │
 │          Installation completed!         │
 │                                          │
 │                                          │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │     Please store your MySQL password!    │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │            a0vW4QKJldIzQetVjvh           │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │      Admin UI: http://10.0.0.4:25500     │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

 ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │   Admin UI default login is admin/admin  │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```